# Why am I getting an "invalid expression" for output voltage and not for other voltages?

Tags: simulation, 555, pspice, monostable

I have designed this monostable (one-shot) vibrator using the 555 timer, yet I am getting this type of error on Pspice for the output voltage only. Where have I gone wrong?

[image: The monostable circuit]

Comment: What do you mean "no output voltage". Do you mean that the output voltage stays at 0 V? How are you measuring it? With scope? With a meter? With just a simulation?

Comment: I'm getting an "invalid expression for Vout" whenever I run the Pspice simulation. The other voltages are working well.

Comment: Then please change the title of your question, because it doesn't reflect your actual issue. Change it to: "Why does Pspice say "invalid expression for Vout"  for this 555 circuit?"

Comment: Yes, you can edit the title. No need to resubmit the question.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, done

Comment: what other voltages are you talking about? ... were you expecting errors for them? ... you did not put the full error message in your question

Comment: The trigger voltage Vtrigger and the capacitor voltage Vc. I can plot their graphs normally.

Comment: perhaps Vout is dependent on a pullup resistor ... have you carefully read the title of your post?

Comment: That's it. Thank you for the heads-up; I totally forgot about this factor. Long day

Comment: I'm now getting a 0V output after adding the 10k pull-up. Is this normal?

Comment: It probably depends on you 555 model. Try adding a load to the output (like a 10k resistor) otherwise it's possible it can't refer properly the signal to ground (net 0)

Answer (score 1):

In the standard monostable circuit, the 555 triggers on the negative-going edge.  With Vcc = 9 V, the Trigger input has to sit above 3 V in the idle state, then go below 3 V to trigger the output.

But ...

The 555 is not a normal monostable.  If the trigger input still is low when the circuit times out (in around 2 s in your case), the output will stay high until the Trigger input goes high.  If the narrow part of your Vtrigger signal is the high part, the circuit will not work because the low part of the trigger signal (2.45 s)is longer than the output period (2 s).

You want Vtrigger to rest high, and go low for 50 ms.

If the trigger signal cannot be adjusted, a solution is to add a differentiator to the Trigger input.  This is a series capacitor between Vtrigger and the Trigger input, and a shunt resistor from the Trigger input to GND.  The time constant should be shorter than 50 ms so it can recover curing the 50 ms Vtrigger period.

Comment: My assignment's given is as follows: Design a monostable (one-shot) circuit using the 555 IC with the following characteristics:
T=2s
Vtrigger=Vpulse with (PW=50ms, PER=2.5s, TD=0, TR=TF=1ms, V1=4V, V2-0V)
Plot (V0, Vc, Vtrigger) versus time. Run to 2.5s. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Turns out I forgot the pullup resistor. Thank you very much

Comment: I'm now getting a 0V output after adding a 10k resistor to the output

Comment: You still have not said whether V1 is the amplitude of the 50 ms pulse, or the amplitude of the signal for the rest of the 2.5 s period.  Also, a 555 does not need a load of any kind to function properly.  It has a totem pole output, and can pull high or low all by itself.